# How i can use result of subquery in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Example, I have SQL - query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
        FROM leads_fields 
        WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244991 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
        as 'coefRL',
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
        FROM leads_fields 
        WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244943 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
        as 'coefWF'

FROM leads
```

And in order to get the difference of these values, I need to duplicate these requests with the 3rd subquery like this?

```
(
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
     FROM leads_fields 
     WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244991 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
        -
     (SELECT value->>"$[0].value" 
      FROM leads_fields 
      WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244943 AND leads_fields.lead_id = leads.external_id)
) as 'difference'
```

Or there are ways more practical, for example `(coefRL - coefWF)` ?

Comment: Have you tried a temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it without a 3rd subquery...

```
SELECT coefRL,
  coefWF,
  coefRL-coefWF difference
FROM
  (SELECT
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value"
    FROM leads_fields
    WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244991
    AND leads_fields.lead_id    = leads.external_id
    ) AS 'coefRL',
    (SELECT value->>"$[0].value"
    FROM leads_fields
    WHERE leads_fields.field_id = 244943
    AND leads_fields.lead_id    = leads.external_id
    ) AS 'coefWF'
  FROM leads
  )
```